# How to extract android backup (.ab) from TWRP?

Tags: android

I've made a backup using "adb backup --twrp" resulting in a single backup.ab file. Using Android Backup extractor suggested here [How to extract or unpack an .ab file (Android Backup file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533567/how-to-extract-or-unpack-an-ab-file-android-backup-file) I'm getting this error

```
Magic: TWRPtwstreamheader
♥↕??ºTWRPtwfilename?m??
Invlaid Magic: TWRPtwstreamheader
♥↕??ºTWRPtwfilename?m??
EVENT: unknown exception occurred:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Magic TWRPtwstreamheader
♥↕??ºTWRPtwfilename?m??
        at org.nick.abe.AndroidBackup.extractAsTar(AndroidBackup.java:639)
        at org.nick.abe.Main.main(Main.java:146)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Magic TWRPtwstreamheader
♥↕??ºTWRPtwfilename?m??
        at org.nick.abe.AndroidBackup.extractAsTar(AndroidBackup.java:414)
        ... 6 more
```

seems like twrp creates different backup format that can't be extracted?

Answer (score 2):

This is [an open issue](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor/issues/60) on Android Backup Extractor's issue tracker. There's apparently [no](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-extract-data-from-adb-twrp-ab-backup.3725347/) [generally](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-recover-data-from-adb-backup-twrp-archive-been-through-hell-and-back.3771615/) working solution for unpacking adb twrp backups. You can try [this tool](https://github.com/arifogel/twrpabx), although it's been archived and hasn't been updated for four years, and [it apparently works for some but not others](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/extract-backup-made-with-adb-with-twrp-option.3577903/). See [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171638/extract-twrp-backups-made-with-adb) for some further suggestions.

Comment: too bad, can I at least select with partitions to recover from twrp with this single .ab file?

Comment: Sorry - don't know.